# Is it known why Periyalwar wrote the following song?

Tags: history, tamil, andal, alvars

Is there any authentic information available as to why Periyalwar wrote this song?

> Periyalwar Tirumoli 300  oru magaḷ tannai uḍaiyēn  ulagam niṛainda
> pugaḻāl     tirumagaḷ pōla vaḷarttēn  ceṅgaṇmāl

and the other songs in this decade? Was he expressing his grief and apprehension about separation from Andal?

Comment: Welcome To HSE! Pls. edit the title of your post to the actual question you want to ask. The main title should look like a question. At its current form the title is unclear.

Comment: Guys no need to DV the question as such. Let OP know how to ask a good question here. We should give  new users a chance to learn from mistakes and rectify. Otherwise the question is all OK.

Comment: Agreed. @SwiftPushkar I have tried to make it clearer. Hope it helps the asker.

Comment: Thanks @Rickross. I was also thinking of doing that but left that on OP so that from further on he will be used  frame the title in specific manner.  Anyway grt. edit.